# how to get correlation between columns in a data frame or matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I have a data frame including 8 columns from X1 to X8. I want to get correlation between X2-X8 and X1 separately, for example X2 and X1, X3 and X1 .... X8 and X1 and finally getting 7 slopes.

```
set.seed(666)
g <- runif(96,1,5)
f <- matrix(g, ncol=8, nrow=12)
F <- data.frame(f)
```

Comment: Try `sapply(2:ncol(F), function(i) cor(F[1], F[i]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe separate into two parts directly as follows:

```r
set.seed(666)
g <- runif(96,1,5)
f <- matrix(g, ncol=8, nrow=12)
F <- data.frame(f)
cor(F[, 1], F[, -1])
#>             X2         X3         X4         X5         X6         X7        X8
#> [1,] -0.231461 -0.1484853 -0.4694454 -0.1203586 -0.3976857 -0.5073719 0.2560319
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: how is it possible to get P-Value and significance for each correlation??

Comment: @Sorena If so, I recommended using `psych::corr.test()`. Note this function is from {psych} package, you need to install it first.